# Manhwa where the female lead has marriages with three different men before being reincarnated/regressed

Tags: story-identification, manga, reincarnation, webcomics

This story involves a female lead as the main character (MC). She had a sad first life. She was married off by her father. This first marriage did not last; I'm not sure why, as I can't remember.

Her second partner/husband was a mage. Through the female lead's memories, it's revealed they seemed to be happy and had a child together. After two years, however, he had lost interest in her and disappeared/ran off with their child, a son.

She is married a third time, to a man that she had known since her first husband. It again seemed to be a political marriage. She was surprised that her family even agreed to it. However, she believed that he was disinterested in her and there was a divide between them, even though he would visit her at night time (wink wink) but he wouldn't speak to her.

At some point, she ends up imprisoned, probably for a crime that she did not commit, I believe orchestrated by her family. As she was getting ready for the end, her current husband came to her and that's when she reincarnated/regressed/died. I remember her flashbacks of him reaching out to her asking her to wait.

In the present time, she is in close contact with her third husband through some type of political stuff, as she tries to bring down her family from her past life. She also encounters the mage that ran off with their child and is using him for gains, too. He is also a flirt.

There may also be a sister who was cruel to her.

I believe the MC may have had different coloured hair from one life to the next.

I've ruled out the following stories so far:

- *The Villainess Turns the Hourglass*
- *The Villainess Lives Twice*
- *I've Been Doted Upon by the Marquis, Who Is Called a Monster*
- *The Invincible Princess Is Bored Again Today*
- *To Those Who Wish for My Destruction*
- *The Heiress' Double Life*
- *Baroness Goes On Strike*
- *I Tamed a Tyrant and Ran Away*
- *I Tamed the Male Lead Who Tried to Kill Me*

Comment: Could you name the stories you've ruled out so far, so we can eliminate them from the search?

Comment: The villainess turns the hourglass, the villainess lives twice, I've been doted on by the marquis whom is called a monster, the invincible princess is bored again, for those who wish to see my demise, the heiress double life, baroness goes on strike, I tamed the tyrany and ran away, I tamed the male lead who tried to kill me

Comment: You mention "manhua" in the title - are you certain this is a Chinese comic? Most of the examples you've ruled out are Korean manhwa (I've Been Doted Upon by the Marquis, Who Is Called a Monster is a Japanese manga)

Comment: Thank you. Yes, you are right. When searching online all the stories mentioned will show up weather searching specifically manhua, manhwa or manga.

Comment: While editing your question, I googled the various story titles you listed in [this comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/284557/manhwa-where-the-female-lead-is-married-to-various-different-men#comment782122_284557), but didn't find one called _"for those who wish to see my demise"_. The closest titles I found were _"To You Who Wish for My Despair"_ and _"To Those Who Wish for My Destruction"_, and since the latter was the closest, I used that in my edit instead. If that's not the story you were referring to, please edit the question yourself to correct that.

Comment: Since you mention that her hair color changes, do you have any idea if she's supposed to be a completely different person after reincarnating/going back in time? Any idea how far back in time she goes? You mention that her son from her second marriage is still around.

Answer (score 3):

[To Those Who Long for My Destruction](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/to-those-who-long-for-my-destruction)?

She was married three times, her first husband was a prince who was murdered, her second husband was a mage who left with her child and her third husband seemed cold and distant and when he went to war she was framed for a crime she did not commit while pregnant. While in jail her sister came and told her that she was going to marry her husband and she wasn’t needed anymore and the female lead ended up using her ability to turn back time to when she was a child.

She’s currently extorting her second husband in her current life to make products so she can have money and is close to both her first and third husband. Her third husband is currently living with her as a child as she made a deal with the emperor to help him succeed.

Chapter 4 - is where it shows the backstory for the three husbands and her turning back time
Chapter 33 - is when she starts to use her second husband for business

Comment: _[To Those Who Long for My Destruction](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/xjwf1re/to-those-who-long-for-my-destruction)_ is an alternate title of _To Those Who Wish for My Destruction_, one the manhwa the OP ruled out in the question.

Comment: It’s the only one that makes sense with the exact specifications they give, I’d say for them to take another look at chapter 4 of the manwha just to make sure